# How to override back button for BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, back, dialogfragment

I know you can override `public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)` but that returns both if the user touches outside of the dialog or if they press the back button.  I just want to get if the user presses the back button.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new Dialog(getActivity(), getTheme()){
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

        }
    };
}
```